# после axios запроса, не обновляется стейт в реакт

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, state

Я пытаюсь получить юзеров через axios запрос. Первый запрос происходит через componentDidMount для получения первой страницы. Он отрабатывает, я получаю первую партию юзеров. Далее когда с помощью пагинации хочу подгрузить еще юзеров, я вызываю отдельную функцию, которая меняет номер страницы в стейте и делает  запрос. Данные приходят, но копирование их в стейт не происходит следовательно стейт не перерисовывается. Что я упустил?

```
import React from 'react'
import './usersPage.scss';
import UsersPageItem from './UsersPageItem';
import defaultAvatar from "./../../../../images/defaultUser.png"
import * as axios from "axios"
import './../../preloader.scss';

let classNames = require('classnames');



class UsersPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: false
        }
        this.totalCount = 0
        this.pagesArray = []
        
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        if (!this.pagesArray.length) {
            this.setState({ isLoading: true })
            axios.get(
                `https://social-network.samuraijs.com/api/1.0/users?page=${this.props.currentUsersPage}&count=${this.props.displayedUsers} `
            )
                .then(response => {
                    this.totalCount = response.data.totalCount
                    if (this.pagesArray.length < response.data.items.length) {
                        this.props.setUsers(response.data.items, response.data.totalCount)
                    }
                    this.setState({ isLoading: false })
                })
        }
    }
    render() {
        let pagesCount = Math.ceil(this.totalCount / this.props.displayedUsers)
        for (let i = 1; i <= pagesCount; i++) {
            this.pagesArray.push(i)
        }
        return (
            <div className="userPage__wrapper">
                {
                    this.state.isLoading
                        ? <section><span className="load"></span></section>
                        : <>
                            {
                                this.props.userBase
                                    //.slice(0, showItem)  =>to show only some elements
                                    ? this.props.userBase.slice(0, this.props.displayedUsers).map((user, index) => (user ? <UsersPageItem
                                        key={this.props.userBase[index].userId}
                                        //data
                                        userBase={this.props.userBase}
                                        currentUserId={this.props.currentUserId}
                                        userAvatar={this.props.userBase[index].avatarUrl
                                            ? this.props.userBase[index].avatarUrl
                                            : defaultAvatar}
                                        userName={this.props.userBase[index].name}
                                        registerDate={this.props.userBase[index].registerDate}
                                        userId={this.props.userBase[index].userId}
                                        statusText={this.props.userBase[index].statusText}
                                        //functions
                                        toFollow={this.props.toFollow}
                                        toChat={this.props.toChat}
                                    /> : null))
                                    : null
                            }
                            <ul className="userPage__pagination-list">
                                <span className="userPage__pagination-list_navig" onClick={(event) => {
                                    
                                   //функция которая не срабатывает//////
                                    this.props.ChangePage(event)
                                   //////////////////////////////////////

                                }}  >prev</span>
                                <div className="userPage__pagination-list_pages-container" >
                                    {/* creating pagination and comparing it with state current selected page */}
                                    {this.pagesArray.slice(0, 10).map(item => <li className={classNames("userPage__pagination-list_item", { " active": item === this.props.currentUsersPage })}
                                        key={item} name={item} onClick={(event) => {
                                            this.props.ChangePage(event)
                                            
                                            this.setState({ isLoading: false })
                                        }}>{item}</li>)}
                                </div>
                                <span className="userPage__pagination-list_navig" onClick={(event) => {
                                    
                                    this.props.ChangePage(event)
                                }}  >next</span>
                                <span className="userPage__pagination-list_total" >total: {this.totalCount}</span>
                            </ul>
                        </>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default UsersPage;


//==============================================================
// код из редьюсера

export let initialUsersState = {
    userBase: [],
    currentUserId: localStorage.getItem("currentUserId"),//<<<==  USER
    displayedUsers: 4,
    totalUsersCount: 0,
    currentUsersPage: 1
}

const userBaseReducer = (state = initialUsersState, action) => {
    let newState = {
        userBase: [...state.userBase],
        ...state
    }
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_USERS":
            return {
                ...newState,
                userBase: [...action.newUsers, ...newState.userBase],
                totalUsersCount: action.totalCount
            }
        case "CHANGE_PAGE":
            const loadData = async (event) => {
                let lastPage = Math.ceil(newState.totalUsersCount / newState.displayedUsers)
                if (event.target.textContent === "prev" && newState.currentUsersPage > 1) {
                    --newState.currentUsersPage
                } else if (event.target.textContent === "next" && newState.currentUsersPage < lastPage) {
                    ++newState.currentUsersPage
                } else if (event.target.attributes.name !== undefined) {
                    newState.currentUsersPage = +event.target.attributes.name.value
                }
                await axios.get(`https://social-network.samuraijs.com/api/1.0/users?page=${newState.currentUsersPage}&count=${newState.displayedUsers}`)
                    .then(response => {

                       //данные из responce получаю
                       // но в стейт копирование не идет
                        return {
                            userBase: [...response.data.items, ...newState.userBase],
                            ...newState,
                        }
                    })
            }
            loadData(action.event)
            break
        default: return newState
    }


    return newState
}

export const SET_USERS_actionCreator = (newUsers, totalCount) => {
    return {
        type: "SET_USERS",
        newUsers: newUsers,
        totalCount: totalCount

    }
}
export const CHANGE_PAGE_actionCreator = (event) => {
    return {
        type: "CHANGE_PAGE",
        event: event
    }
}

//==============================================================
// код из коннектора

import PublicUserPage from './../UserPage/PublicUserPage';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {
    SET_USERS_actionCreator,
    CHANGE_PAGE_actionCreator
} from './../../../../redux/userBaseReducer';

let mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        userBase: state.usersReducer.userBase,
        currentUserId: state.usersReducer.currentUserId,
        displayedUsers: state.usersReducer.displayedUsers,
        totalUsersCount: state.usersReducer.totalUsersCount,
        currentUsersPage: state.usersReducer.currentUsersPage
    }
}
let mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {//functions for connect is dispatch
    return {
        setUsers: (newUsers, totalCount) => {
            dispatch(SET_USERS_actionCreator(newUsers, totalCount))
        },
        ChangePage: (event) => {
            dispatch(CHANGE_PAGE_actionCreator(event))
        }
    }
}


const PublicUserPageContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PublicUserPage)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо сделать Separation of Concerns в вашем коде. Полезно было бы перечитать туториал по Редаксу - https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts.

То, как организован ваш store нарушает важное правило Редакса - редьюсеры не могут содержать side effects, в том числе асинхронных запросов. Редьюсер - это всегда банальная функция, которая не занимается сложной логикой.

Асинхронные запросы должны обрабатываться отдельными функциями. Как правило, в простых случаях используется middleware - thunks - https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk.

Правильный флоу в таком случае выглядит так:

1. Событие (клик по линку)

```
<span className="userPage__pagination-list_navig" onClick={this.getData}>prev</span>
```

2. Вызов метода компонента getData(), возвращающую промис, обрабатывающий результат ajax-запроса, например, показывает попап с success/error.

```
    getData() {
          // requestUsers() - это thunk, который так же передается через connect
          return actions.requestUsers()
            .then(() => { console.log('success') }
            .catch((error) => {console.log(error)}))
        }
```

3. Вызов thunk-функции, где в случае success происходит диспатч соответствующего action.

```
        function requestUsers() {
          //thunks have access dispatch
          return async dispatch => {
            try {
              const res = await axios.get(url)
              
              dispatch(setUserListSuccess(res.data))
              
              return res
            } catch {
              dispatch(setUserListError())
              through new Error('error')
            }
          }
        }
```

4. Action creator передает соответствующий action и данные в редьюсер. А редьюсер возвращает новый объект с данными.

```
        // Action creator
        function setUsers(data) {
          return {
            type: 'CHANGE_PAGE',
            data
          }
        }
    
        // Reducer
        const userBaseReducer = (state = [], action) => {
          switch (action.type) {
            case "CHANGE_PAGE":
              return [
                ...state,
                action.data
              ]
          }
        }
```

5. Реакт видит обновление пропсов и рендерит новый вью.

Comment: Довольно подробно, спасибо.